# One end user intermittently unable to access file share over Cisco VPN

Tags: cisco-vpn

Users connect to our network remotely via Cisco AnyConnect Client software to our ASA 5505.  Most users are having no issues at all, but I have one user who sometimes has the situation where she's able to connect, I can see she's connected, but she cannot access our network file shares (Win 2012 R2 server).  She gets the error that it cannot find the location, and to make sure it's correct.  We've tried accessing it via IP instead, and she gets the same message - even though she can ping the IP successfully.  All AnyConnect settings are the same as our other machines, including the software version.  She's running Windows 10, same as we are everywhere else.

Usually some combination of rebooting a few times, and/or turning off and on the Windows Firewall allows her to connect successfully, but not always.  We have no idea if these actions are doing anything or not, as the connection success or failure has not consistently tied to any factor yet.  Her IP isn't blocked on this end, and I'm not seeing any errors in the logs on the ASA connected to her IP or anything related.  Also of note, when she turns off the firewall and connects, then turns it back on she can (usually) still connect just fine.  Until the next time it decides to stop.

This issue has happened in multiple different locations (and succeeded sometimes from those same locations), so it doesn't seem to be ISP related.

The intermittent nature of this is really puzzling me.  Anyone have any ideas about what else I could check?  Thank you!

Comment: Cisco AnyConnect is a finicky product. Have you tried reinstalling it? It is not unusual that AnyConnect decides to block connections or fail DNS queries for one silly reason or another that requires a service restart or reboot. Could be some other combination too, like another firewall product or security application. Remember, it’s not “just” a VPN client.

Comment: We've tried reinstalling, yes.  The only other security product on there is Avira, and it's the same thing - whether or not it's on or off doesn't reliably affect whether or not she can connect.